# Magento 2 - change database in etc/env.php

Tags: magento2

**My environment:**

1. Magento 2.0.7
2. Production mode
3. Cache enabled

I cloned current Database that my store has been normaly working with:

> original_db

and named it:

> original_db_dev

All DB details that changed are: database name, and user name. The rest (host, password) remained the same.

I change details in `etc/env.php` file by simply replacing appriopriate data. Then flush the cache. However, although the DB is cloned (= is exactly the same as the original one) the store it's not working. I'm getting error:

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number:
>   455082819174

**Questions**

1. How can I found out more about the error? Nothing is generated in var/log
2. How can I fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: check `var/report/455082819174` file

Comment: Please paste your error content from file var/report/455082819174

Comment: Trivial access denied error. Thanks chirag!